# Choosing technlogy for a website. Ajax or push?

Tags: ajax, client-server, push

We are building a website with has some functionality similar to bigdeal.com. We are not building an auction site or anything like that, but some sections of the website will be updating frequently given other users actions (similar to bidding on bigdeal.com). The page will be continually updated every time some user causes different events.

We were wondering if this can be done using just ajax, or if its necessary something like smartfoxserver.com or pusher.com

thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how essential the real-time aspect is. For example, for a chat website, push is essential for real-time communication. For a website where latency is less of a problem, you may wish to poll with AJAX every once in a while. As a real life example, Twitter.com at least used to show a few recent tweets on their home page. This was powered by AJAX, as it was not essential for everyone to see every recent tweet coming in as soon as it came in. For your purposes, it looks like AJAX will be alright.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
So, in case that real-time is essential, we should go with push. The thing is that otherwise we would have to make an ajax request every second, wich may cause browser degradation.

Comment: @Nicolas: I wouldn't suggest making an AJAX request every second. The way Twitter did it was they returned things from, say, five minutes ago. When it was finished displaying those (which might take a minute or two), it would request more from where it stopped.